# Continuity and closeness of linear operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider spaces $X=C’[0,1]$ and $Y=C[0,1]$ both with sup norm with $f,g,h : X\to Y$ defined by $f(x)=x+x’$, $g(x)=x(1)+x’(1)$ and $h(x)=x’+\int_0^tx$. I have to find which maps among $f$, $g$ and $h$ are continuous and which one are closed .

I know that derivative map is not bounded as $\| (x_n)’\|$ is not bounded and hence none of the map is continuous. Am I right ?  I am unable to check closeness. I am trying for $f$. If $x_n\to x$ in $X$ and $x_n+x_n’\to y$ in $Y$, how to think about $T(x)=y$? Please let me the process for all of these maps . Thank you.

Comment: $(y-x)(t)=\lim \int_0^{t} x_n'(s)ds=\int_0^{t} x(s)ds$. Differentiate this.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for comment. Please let me for others maps also .

Comment: If I take derivative then I got  $y’=x+x’$ but not the same as $T(x)=y?$.

Comment: $y(t)=y(0)+\int_0^{t} [x(s)+x'(s)]ds$. Can you finish?

Comment: $h$ is closed and the proof is very similar to that of $f$.

Comment: @geetha290krm and for $h$ it’s also closed ?

Comment: @geetha290krm but for $f$ am not even see that $T(x)=y$ as $x+x’=y$. Sorry for that .

Comment: @geetha290krm can I say that $ x_n’$ is uniformly convergent to $y-x$ and hence $x’=y-x$ which says that $y=x+x’$?